# Opencart check if product has options

Tags: opencart, categories

Currently my Opencart site only lets me 'Add to Cart' on the categories page, however if a product has options like 'colour' etc I want it to say 'View Product' instead.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? I have tried editing the category.php controller to check if a product has options but cannot seem to get it working properly.

Thanks.

*Update*

So far I have added:

```
$options = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($result['product_id']);
```

Above this array $this->data['products'] = array(); in catalog>controller>product>category.php

This was my attempt to check if a product has options or not. Then I added in catalog>view>theme>mytheme>template>product>category.tpl

```
<?php if ($product['options']) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"  class="button" />View Product</a>

<?php } else { // EO CATALOGUE MODE ?>

<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />

 <?php } ?>
```

But it is not quite cutting the mustard.

Comment: You have to tell us what you have done. Also, put the part of `category.php` that you have edited. Update your questions with the them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the options to the `$products` array which is what you are checking in `category.tpl`:

Look for:

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
```

and add the options as an index to each product array

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
    'options' => $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($result['product_id']),
```